# Collection_select multiple: true. Почему первый элемент в массиве params[:book][:genre_ids] = ["","1","2"] всегда пустой

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Модели:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :book_genres
  has_many :genres, through: :book_genres
end

class Genre < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :book_genres
  has_many :books, through: :book_genres
end

class BookGenre < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :genre
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @book do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.collection_select(:genre_ids, Genre.all, :id, :genre, {include_blank: "Select genre"}, {multiple: true, size: 6}) %>
  ...
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

books_controller.rb

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @book = Book.new
  end
  def create
    render plain: params.inspect
  end
end
```

Параметры:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {
  "utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"8WRSXJHwMyHM....",
  "book"=>{"title"=>"",
           "genre_ids"=>["", "2", "3", "4"],
           "desc"=>"",
           "published_at"=>"1982"}, 
  "commit"=>"Create Book", 
  "controller"=>"books",
  "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

Не могу понять, почему в массиве "genre_ids"=>["", "2", "3", "4"] первый элемент всегда пустой.

Answer (score 1):

Это связано с тем, что у вас в хелпер `collection_select` включен параметр

```
include_blank: "Select genre"
```

Он предназначен для позиции в выпадающем списке, когда ничего не выбрано. Значение этой дополнительной option-позиции не задано и позволяет определить, что список остался не заполненным. В вашем случае (множественный выбор) этот параметр не требуется и его можно убрать.

Comment: <%= f.collection_select(:genre_ids, Genre.all, :id, :genre, {}, {multiple: true, size: 6}) %>  Ничего не изменилось